# Python Dictionary-Bot Questions

Tags: python, discord.py

I was making a discode dictionary bot. The function I want is for the user to enter a word and the meaning of the word through a command to the bot.
So what's been conceived!It's input (word) (meaning), but the problem is that the bot separates words and their meanings by spaces, so if the meaning gets longer, only the sentence before the space is saved as meaning.
For example, if you type !input anarchism is a~~,
When you print it out, it only outputs up to anarchism.
I think it's because there's a space between the word anarchism and is. Please look at my code and answer me how to fix it.

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=discord.Intents.all())

front_command = "!"

user_input = ""

user_output = ""

check_number = 0



@bot.event

async def on_ready():

    print('Logging in..: ')

    print(bot.user.name)

    print('connection was succesful')

    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Testing"))



@bot.command()

async def input(ctx, arg1, arg2):

    global check_number

    temp_f = open("user.txt","r")

    datafile = temp_f.readlines()

    if len(datafile) == 0:

        temp_f.close()

        temp_f = open("user.txt","w")

        temp_f.write(ctx.author.name + " " + str(arg1) + " " + str(arg2) +"\n")

        await ctx.send("Registration completed!")

    else:

        for i in range(len(datafile)):

            if arg1 in datafile[i]:

                temp_f.close()

                temp_f = open("user.txt","w")

                datafile[i] = ctx.author.name + " " + str(arg1) + " " + str(arg2) +"\n"

                temp_f.write('\n'.join(datafile))

                await ctx.send("There is aleready "+str(arg1)+" related input, so it is changed to input now!")

                check_number = 1

                break

    

    if check_number == 0:

        temp_f = open("user.txt","w")

        temp_f.write(ctx.author.name + " " + str(arg1) + " " + str(arg2) +"\n")

        await ctx.send("Registration completed!")

    

    check_number = 0

    temp_f.close()







@bot.command()

async def output(ctx, arg1):

    global check_number

    temp_f = open("user.txt","r")

    datafile = temp_f.readlines()

    if len(datafile) == 0:

        await ctx.channel.send("Nothing's registered yet! :)")

    else:

        for i in range(len(datafile)):

            if arg1 in datafile[i]:

                info = datafile[i].split()

                msg = await ctx.send(str(info[2]))

                await msg.reply(str(info[0]) + " " + "wrote this!")

                check_number = 1

                break



    if check_number == 0:

        await ctx.channel.send("Nothing's registered yet! :)")



    check_number = 0

bot.run('Token')
```

Comment: u can trying separate word using method `split()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

You can add a `*` before your last argument to get everything the User has written, like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def input(ctx, arg1, *, arg2):
```

You could also circumvent it by having the user surround the input in quotes, in your example it would be: `!input anarchism "your definition here"`, but the method above is more user-friendly.